# Can I see which of my edit suggestions were approved?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I don't have edit privileges. Can I see this? Not just recent but the whole list. I just want to know why some may not have been approved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under your Programmer's profile, click `activity` in the middle of the page, click `suggestions` and click on any of the `suggested edit` links to determine the information about the accepted or rejected status:

[image]